# 403 No valid crumb was included in the request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am running a Spring Boot Application and trying to test the application using "spring-boot-starter-test". While testing the web services I get a Response with status code 403 -  No valid crumb was included in the request. I am unable to figure out what is missing in the request. I am able to test the service through POSTMAN, however the same request details are failing during Unit Testing.

```
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "POST /new-game 

HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Accept: */*[\r][\n]"
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Content-Length: 40[\r][\n]"
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Host: localhost:8080[\r][\n]"
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.7 (Java/1.8.0_144)[\r][\n]"
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "[\r][\n]"
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> POST /new-game HTTP/1.1
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Accept: */*
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Content-Length: 40
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Host: localhost:8080
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Connection: Keep-Alive
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.7 (Java/1.8.0_144)
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "{"firstMove":true,"playerName":"Adarsh"}"
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "HTTP/1.1 403 No valid crumb was included in the request[\r][\n]"
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Date: Sun, 31 Mar 2019 19:48:53 GMT[\r][\n]"
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff[\r][\n]"
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store[\r][\n]"
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1[\r][\n]"
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Content-Length: 389[\r][\n]"
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Server: Jetty(9.4.z-SNAPSHOT)[\r][\n]"
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "[\r][\n]"
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.DefaultClientConnection - Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 403 No valid crumb was included in the request
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << HTTP/1.1 403 No valid crumb was included in the request
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Date: Sun, 31 Mar 2019 19:48:53 GMT
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Content-Length: 389
2019-03-31 14:48:53 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Server: Jetty(9.4.z-SNAPSHOT)
```

Comment: I was able to solve this issue by removing the "spring-boot-starter-test" and "httpclient" dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by removing the "spring-boot-starter-test" and "httpclient" dependencies. Now I am using "rest-assured" for testing the web services.